# Multithreading using std::bind - Unsure how to pass parameters

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, stdbind

process_data.h:

```
void computeAvgFactor(const int*, int, int, double&);
    void computeVarFactor(const int*, int, int, double, double&);
    class ProcessData {
        int total_items{};
        int* data{};
        int num_threads{ 0 }; // to hold number of threads 
        double* averages{ nullptr }; // to hold average factors 
        double* variances{ nullptr }; // to hold variance factors
        int* p_indices{ nullptr }; // to hold partitioning indices
    public:
        ProcessData(std::string, int n_threads);
        ProcessData(const ProcessData&) = delete;
        ProcessData& operator=(const ProcessData&) = delete;
        ~ProcessData();
        int operator()(std::string, double&, double&);
    };
```

process_data.cpp:

```
void computeAvgFactor(const int* arr, int size, int divisor, double& avg)
    {
        avg = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            avg += arr[i];
        }
        avg /= divisor;
    }

void computeVarFactor(const int* arr, int size, int divisor, double avg, double& var)
    {
        var = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            var += (arr[i] - avg) * (arr[i] - avg);
        }
        var /= divisor;
    }

int ProcessData::operator()(std::string filename, double& avg, double& var)
    {
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        int nParts = total_items / num_threads;

        for (int i = 0; i < num_threads;i++)
        {
            auto p = std::bind(computeAvgFactor, &data[p_indices[i]], nParts, total_items, averages[i]);
            threads.push_back(std::thread(p));
        }
        for (auto& thread : threads)
        {
            thread.join();
        }
        threads.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < num_threads;i++)
        {
            avg += averages[i];
        }
    }
```

The constructor simply loads info from a binary file, and is already 100% working.

I ran into 2 issues, the first one was that I could not bind with placeholders outside of the `for` loop, because every time I did I get errors `C2893` and `C2672` about invalid parameters:

```
auto p = std::bind(computeAvgFactor, _1, _2, &total_items, _3);

for (int i = 0; i < num_threads;i++)
{
    threads.push_back(std::thread(p, &data[p_indices[i]], nParts, averages[i]));
}
```

I solved this by just binding it inside the `for` loop.

However, the second problem, which I have now, is that the `averages[i]` which is being passed into the `computeAvgFactor` function is not storing anything when the functions exits. I figure this is because I need to pass it by reference, but if I use `&averages[i]` I get `C2672` and `C2893` errors.

I guess I am just grossly misunderstanding.

Comment: Why did you write `&total_items` in the non-working version when you wrote only `total_items` in the working version? That obviously changes what you pass as argument

Comment: Why are you even bothering with `std::bind()` at all, rather than using a lambda? ie: `threads.push_back( [&](){ computeAvgFactor(&data[p_indices[i]], nParts, total_items, averages[i] } );`